# ros fuerte rosdoc does not generate index.html

Tags: ros, rosdoc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

I had a system running with multiple own ros packages using electric on ubuntu 10.04
I upgraded to ros fuerte and ubuntu 12.04
Now I have the problem when I run the command

```
rosrun rosdoc rosdoc camera1394 vision_msgs
```

which are own packages, then I get a bunch of warnings, but no errors, and inside the "doc" folder the two packages documentation are generated, but the main "index.html" is missing

The log can be found [here](http://paste.org/56665)
which contains a bunch of warnings about missing paths, but the the point is, even with missing paths, they are still warnings, and this shouldn't affect the generation of main index.html, right?

**Edit1**

Another interesting example is a project that uses *actionlib* package(defined int the manifest), and rosdoc is throwing the warning

> warning: tag INCLUDE_PATH: include path `/opt/ros/fuerte/share/actionlib/include' does not exist

> warning: source /opt/ros/fuerte/share/actionlib/include is not a readable file or directory... skipping.

this path is defined inside the local CMakeFiles, but in fuerte, the path

> /opt/ros/fuerte/share/actionlib

exists while its /include directory is in

> /opt/ros/fuerte/include/actionlib

Is that a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47559/ros-fuerte-rosdoc-does-not-generate-index.html/) by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's not a top level index.html expected, above the level of each package.  The others are just warnings and are due to providing robustness to different package layouts.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0